# .net wrapper for twitter v1.1 API

Tags: .net, twitter

I couldn't find any .net library for twitter 1.1 API

is there any library for .net available for twitter api version 1.1?

Answer (score 2):

I recently upgraded LINQ to Twitter to Twitter v1.1 API: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score -1):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#dotnet
and also: http://code-inside.de/blog/2009/04/20/howto-twittern-mit-c/

Comment: Twitter API was still 1.0 in 2009. That blog post is obsolete.